# How to get the line number of error inside of catch on ajax call in javascript

Tags: javascript, axios

When I use try, catch I can get line number of error by stack message.
But When I use this for ajax call as below,

```
try {
 await axios.get('http://example.com')
} catch (error) {
 console.log(error)
}
```

I can't get the stack error. It just gives me error of ajax call.
Isn't there any method for catching the line number in this case?
Thank you for reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `error` will contain enough information to identify the problem. `error` is an object, when you do `console.log(error)`, it actually calls its `toString` implementation.

To get the stack only, you can use.

```js
try {
    throw new Error('Test');
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.stack);
}
```

The above will only point to the JavaScript file/piece of code that fires the request to `example.com`, nothing more. :)

If you want to see what happened with your call (more details of why it failed), and what was the response, try `console.log(JSON.stringify(error))` and use **Network DevTools** - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network